# PowerShell Syntax Highlighting

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I mainly answer PHP questions where syntax highlighting has always worked for me with just indentation.  I've just started using PowerShell and have asked a couple of questions and syntax highlighting seems to be wonky:

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\third.ps1"
#get $Current  = second.ps1
#get $Caller   = first.ps1 
#get $Original = first.ps1

$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

$action = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($myInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
```

**Wouldn't even some default syntax highlighting get one of the most common comment `#` styles right?**

[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) states in [Get original script name included script name and possibly others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67928074/get-original-script-name-included-script-name-and-possibly-others/67928547#67928547) that using **```sh** is a hack to get it to work:

```sh
    . "$PSScriptRoot\third.ps1"
    #get $Current  = second.ps1
    #get $Caller   = first.ps1 
    #get $Original = first.ps1

    $wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
    $wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
    $wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
    
    $action = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($myInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
```

Comment: the [[tag:powershell]] has syntax highlighting set to "default" (scroll to the very bottom of the page). So, there isn't a powershell specific highlighting.

Comment: Using code fences (\`\`\`) with an explicit language (\`\`\`sh) over code blocks (indenting by 4 spaces) has been recommend since the markdown overall anyway; so if you get in the habit of doing so you'll likely have a better experience.

Comment: support this FR: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355370/please-bring-a-version-of-highlight-js-which-supports-powershell-onto-stack-exch?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Unless my 4 beers have totally F' ed me, it's happening with PHP mix HTML also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943395/php-how-to-echo-across-the-whole-page/67943593#67943593

Comment: The canonical is *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109)*. PowerShell is not mentioned at all in the list of supported languages (***"PowerShell is not supported by the Stack Exchange version of highlight.js."***). At a minimum, [the most commonly used cmdlets](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2014/12/breaking-into-powershell.html) (and [their aliases](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2019/10/powershell-aliases-and-missing.html)) should be supported, but they just look weird when trying to use Bash or similar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't shed any light on the *why*, but the highlighter isn't even defaulting to anything here, it's just doing *nothing*. Setting the block manually to `lang-default` has [seemingly better results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woXCE.png):

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\third.ps1"
#get $Current  = second.ps1
#get $Caller   = first.ps1 
#get $Original = first.ps1

$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

$action = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($myInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
```

So to answer your question

> Wouldn't even some default syntax highlighting get one of the most common comment `#` styles right?

The answer is actually *yes*, the highlighter just isn't defaulting to anything here for some reason.

---

Also, calling the triple backticks method (```` ```sh ````) a "hack" is a little weird... It's an [officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#hinting-tags) way of specifying the highlighting language. In this case, you're specifying the *tag* [sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sh), which tells the highlighter to use the language code specified by that tag.

In this case, [sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sh) [is set to `lang-sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sh/info#prev-value), so it gives you the same results as if you set the block to use `lang-sh` manually (note that this language id happens to be synonymous with `lang-bash` & `lang-zsh`):

```sh
. "$PSScriptRoot\third.ps1"
#get $Current  = second.ps1
#get $Caller   = first.ps1 
#get $Original = first.ps1

$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

$action = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($myInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I call it a "hack" because PowerShell syntax is not shell, bash or zsh.  I will test with `lang-c` and see what it does.  And would it not be a bug to not default to anything?

Comment: That makes sense; it's disappointing that some languages just aren't supported. At least this is a case where what's available is seemingly close-ish.

Comment: It looks like it does have *some* colouring based on the fact that some of the text is syntax highlighted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64243652/2029983)

Comment: @Larnu It does look like it worked in that case, even if it's still [using the bash highlighter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMhzO.png). If I had to guess (since they OP didn't share a link), the no-highlight that OP saw probably is due to tags on the question, since that's been known to affect the applied highlighter. I've forgotten the specifics of that though.

Comment: Seems like it's hit an miss, @zcoop98 . For the OP's code, it doesn't work at all: [Sandbox attempt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366411/397219)

Comment: I think you know this but just in case: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355370

Comment: @Larnu Let me clarify (though you might be spot on that I'm wrong about this case), I dug up the post I was thinking of. [This post by animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354679/please-default-to-typescript-formatting-for-typescript-posts/354695#354695) explains how tags interact with the highlighter. "[W]e revert to "default" if there are two tags on a question that have different highlighters set."

Comment: @Larnu In your SO answer that you shared, that question has a 4 tags, and exactly one of them has a language set: [[tag:powershell]], set to "default". If OP's answer, on the other hand, was on a question with >1 highlighted tag, it may have failed to highlight altogether (which I've definitely seen in the wild before).

Comment: In all cases I use `\`\`\`powershell` though @zcoop98 , so that statement shouldn't apply.

Comment: @Larnu Gotcha! I definitely missed that detail on your's.

Comment: Even `sh` and `powershell` are not good. For example,  highlighting `Get-date` on a line by itself with either option will see the `-` as a subtraction operator and then highlight the `Get` and `date` differently.

Answer (score 3):

There is **no great option for powershell** right now.

For example, with `lang-powershell`:

```powershell
Get-date
```

Or with  ```` ```sh ````

```sh
Get-date
```

Both cases see the `-` as a subtraction operator and then show the words "Get" and "date" in different colors. The third case doesn't do anything at all. Yet clearly this is one call to the `Get-date` cmdlet.

There's also  ```` ```powershell ````

```
Get-date
```

which does *nothing at all*, and  ```` ```lang-default ````

```
Get-date
```

which at least allows some kind of detection to work but still gets it wrong.