# Proper syntax highlighting for PowerShell

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting, powershell

Tagging a fenced code block with `powershell`:

````
```powershell
Write-Output "Hello, $Env:USERNAME"
```
````

produces *no* syntax highlighting:

```
Write-Output "Hello, $Env:USERNAME"
```

[image: PowerShell snippet with no highlighting]

This behavior holds for other common aliases for PowerShell - `ps`, `ps1`, etc.

You can trick it into the default highlighter by using `lang-powershell` or the sh highlighter using `sh` (as is mentioned in [other questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408345/powershell-syntax-highlighting) ):

[image: powershell snippet with crude highlighting]

which is better than nothing, but is imperfect; note now the environment variable within the interpolated string is not properly highlighted as a variable. Compare vs. the standard syntax highlighter built into Windows:

[image]

So there are really two requests here:

1. At *least* offer the default syntax highlighter on the `powershell` and `ps` names. For example, the block below uses the `cs` name, not the verbose `lang-cs`. I didn't even know about the need for the `lang-` prefix until I started researching this feature request, since I'd always been able to discover the short-form by guessing! The `lang-` prefix is non-discoverable and you *have* to go to documentation to learn about it, I've never seen it in any other Markdown implementation of fenced-code-blocks.  It's not even mentioned in the formatting-help sidebar.  Using `lang-default` or `sh` are non-discoverable workarounds that shouldn't be necessary.

   ```cs
   Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {Environment.UserName}.");
   ```
2. Ideally, a proper syntax highlighter for PowerShell that understands the language fully, including its string-interpolation syntax. Note how the C# snippet above gets proper `$"string interpolation"`

Related questions:

- [Syntax highlighting: Use "lang-bash" (or similar) as default language for tags [powershell] and [powershell-core] until PowerShell is fully supported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421022/syntax-highlighting-use-lang-bash-or-similar-as-default-language-for-tags)

  This question is very informative about root-cause, but primarily focuses on the Stack Exchange tagging behavior and not fenced code blocks.  Under that mechanism, using a `powershell` tag (but not a `powershell-core` tag) on the post does cause the `lang-default`, which is related to my request (1).  However, as shown above that does not work for fenced code blocks. This is important since PowerShell is often involved answer to various Windows admin tasks on Super User and Server Fault that may not be tagged with `powershell`.
- [Enable automatic and on-demand syntax highlighting for PowerShell (updated for highlight.js)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421016/enable-automatic-and-on-demand-syntax-highlighting-for-powershell-updated-for-h)

  Functionally the same as above but includes more technical background.  In  particularly useful as it explains *why* the SE team is hesitant to add more languages (they have a performance load).  This is used to explain why syntax highlighting for Julia was deferred.

  However, PowerShell is an order-of-magnitude more questioned than Julia, and even now measures beyond Bash:

  https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=powershell%2Clisp%2Cperl%2Cbash%2Ccmd%2Cscheme%2Cgo%2Cjulia

  [image: graph of language popularity showing PowerShell]

Comment: Sorry, this is meant to be a feature-request for SO, not a request for tips on how to do Powershell syntax highlighting.  Yes, the "sh" hack works, but it's not an ideal workflow.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, correct me if I'm wrong, but this feature request is rather loosely related to question in linked post.

Comment: Point 1 can be done by a mod if they see fit. Point 2 is not something SE will solve unless the Highlight.js already has the implementation and isn't a resource hog when integrated by SE.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421016/enable-automatic-and-on-demand-syntax-highlighting-for-powershell-updated-for-h?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You'll see that I've already referenced that in the related questions section, and that's about *tags*, when I'm talking about fenced code blocks.

Comment: @Pxtl I can't tell whether you've realized this, but one of the things that post references is that when you use `\`\`\`powershell` on a code block, you're telling the highlighter to look at the _[[tag:powershell]] tag's_ defined highlighter for it to use; that's why tags are related here. In order to fix `\`\`\`powershell`, we _have_ to fix the associated tag's selected highlighter.